# How do I use external files in my Wix installer?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I'm not sure if this is a Wix or a Visual Studio issue but here goes:

I've basically created a small installer that installs a PowerShell Module to `%USERPROFILE%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\DatabaseUserManagement`. The directory tree in my .wxs file looks like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
               Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="PersonalFolder">
        <Directory Id="WindowsPowerShellDir"
                   Name="WindowsPowerShell">
          <Directory Id="ModulesDir"
                     Name="Modules">
            <Directory Id="DatabaseUserManagementDir"
                       Name="DatabaseUserManagement">
              <Component Id="CMP_DatabaseUserManagementDLL"
                         Guid="MY-GUID-HERE">
                <File Id="FILE_DatabaseUserManagementDir_DatabaseUserManagementDLL"
                      Source="Files\DatabaseUserManagement.dll"
                      KeyPath="yes"/>
              </Component>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

Now this doesn't compile because DatabaseUserManagement.dll is actually added to the solution as a link and therefore doesn't exist in the 'Files' subdirectory.

The error is straightforward enough: 
 `The system cannot find the file 'Files\DatabaseUserManagement.dll'.`

What I'm trying to do is when the project builds, I want it to copy the dll from it's original location (For the sake of example, let's say it's C:\Files\DatabaseUserManagement.dll) into the project under the 'Files' subdirectory and then build the project.

Is there any way to achieve this, or do I have to manually copy this DLL every time I update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DLL is referenced by another project in your solution, you could reliably take it from the output folder of that project, as long as `Copy to local` is set to true in the properties.

Alternatively a pre-build event could copy the file to the required location for you.